# How does firebase cloud messaging map an FCM token to an APNs token

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to get my head around how FCM actually works in Flutter. What's strange to me is that you can call:

```dart
FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
```

and retrieve a token, even before the user has authorised the app for notifications. What's confusing to me is that:

1. I don't see anywhere where the FCM token is actually being uploaded to my FCM instance.
2. Once the user has authorised the app for notifications, how is the APNS token that is generated on acceptance actually linked/mapped to the one already in the FCM instance?

Furthermore, I always get the warning:

```
APNS device token not set before retrieving FCM Token for Sender ID '123412341234'. Notifications to this FCM Token will not be delivered over APNS.Be sure to re-retrieve the FCM token once the APNS device token is set.
```

But I can't see how to set the APNS token, or re-retrieve the token once the APNS token is set. Notifications are working on a real iOS device, so I don't see why i'm getting this message.

The docs are a little thin on the actual explanation of how FCM is communicating with an app instance in order to stay in sync with it. Can anyone help me understand this a bit better?

Comment: For this you need to have a look at the Firebase SDK's source code https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk

Comment: The APNS token is retrieved by the SDK automatically via swizzling, and then set within the SDK. After setting it, eventually this function gets called: fetchNewTokenWithAuthorizedEntity https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/eb30b6fdd809cbfe3a9eb7f3ccf1dd46326bef2d/FirebaseMessaging/Sources/Token/FIRMessagingTokenManager.m#L259 this sends a request to Firebase servers to get a new FCM "instance ID" (token) which is used to uniquely identify the device+app instance btw, not just for notifications.